# Kendo Grid Edit Cancel delete Previously saved Row

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to update my previously saved entry into a Kendo Grid, but whenever the edit popup window is cancelled, then that row gets deleted.

Here is my Kendo Grid Code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Rezcue.Models.PassengerGrid>()
    .Name("Passenger")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.PassengerID).Width(50);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Width(100);
        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(160);
    })
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
        .Events(x=>x.Change("Test"))
        .Model(model => { model.Id(p => p.PassengerID); model.Field(x => x.PassengerID); model.Field(x => x.Name); })
        .Read(read => read.Action("PassengerDetailTemplate", "GetData"))
        .Create(update => update.Action("EditingPopup_Update", "GetData"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("EditingPopup_Update", "GetData"))
        .Destroy(update => update.Action("EditingPopup_Destroy", "GetData"))
    )
)
```

Comment: Both your `Create` and `Update` buttons point to the same `Action` `EditingPopup_Update`. Paste your Controller here without which no one will be able to tell whats going on.